# How do philosophical movements form? Never understood how something like logical empiricism becomes a "movement"?

Tags: movement

How do philosophical movements form? Never understood how something like logical empiricism becomes a "movement"?

Someone invents an "ism". Others start using it?

Comment: People met around a "teacher" : Moritz Schlick for [Vienna Circle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vienna-circle/) and [Hans Reichenbach](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reichenbach/) for The Berlin Society for Empirical (or Scientific) Philosophy.

Comment: You must have seen how ideas go viral on the internet? Well, when it is a whole cluster of ideas, and they last, you get a movement. It helps when there is a charismatic figure in the middle, like James (pragmatism) or Husserl (phenomenology). For logical positivists that was Wittgenstein. Self-identifying tag helps too. Want to start one? For a more recent know-how (1990s) see [transhumanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhumanism).

Comment: @Conifold I have formulated views that could motivate movements. Particularly, because they are meant to expand/advance on previous thought models.